# Help finding Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

The matrix is \begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & -2 \\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I got the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 1 + 2i$, and $\lambda_3 = 1-2i$. I am only concerned with the complex valued eigenvectors. For $\lambda_2$, I got the eigenvector
\begin{equation*} v_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
i \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} and for $\lambda_3$, I got the eigenvector

\begin{equation*}v_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-i \\
1
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

In the back of the book, it is saying the eigenvectors for $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are \begin{equation*} v_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-i
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
and \begin{equation*}v_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
i
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

When I checked on Wolfram Alpha, it is saying that my answers are correct. Did I do something wrong or is the back of my book wrong?

Comment: Your $v_2$ and the book's $v_2$ differ by a scalar multiple, so they're both eigenvectors for $\lambda_2$. Similarly for $v_3$. So you and the book are both correct.

Comment: Looks absolutely fine to me. As the previous comment noted, eigenvectors for one-dimensional eigenspaces are only defined up to a scalar multiple. If the eigenspace is larger than that, you're just pulling two or more vectors out of a large space and I would generally not expect software to necessarily give the same answer.

Comment: Ah I see now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=1-2i,\lambda_3=1+2i$

$$v_1=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]\longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
x_3 \\
-\frac{3}{2}\cdot x_3 \\
x_3 \\
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 \\
-\frac{3}{2} \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

$$v_2=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 2i & -2 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 2i & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]\longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 \\
-i\cdot x_3 \\
x_3 \\
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 \\
-i \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

$$v_3=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
-2i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -2i & -2 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & -2i & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]\longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 \\
i\cdot x_3 \\
x_3 \\
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 \\
i \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right]$$